# Send adaptive card base on command in power virtual agent

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, power-virtual-agents

I am trying to send adaptive card from power virtual agent through command. My flow run successfully but adaptive card not show after enter the command

[image]

[image]

Comment: please expand the "post adaptive card" action in your screenshot, so we can see what it's actually configured to do. For instance, is it set to post to the correct team? Or is it supposed to post to the user. Also, what is it configured to post "as" - Flow Bot, or this Power Virtual Agent? We need to see that to help properly.

Comment: Could you please check if you have configured the correct team or not?

Comment: Is your issue resolved or are you still looking for any help?